# Will deleting files on my computer delete them them in Ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

OK. So I usually save my files online and not on my computer. I am hoping to be able to set up my Ubuntu One cloud to recognize changes made to documents and add new documents when synchronizing. But not delete from the cloud, files I have deleted from my computer. Does anyone know if this is possible? I have searched around and can't figure out the answer to my question. I would appreciate any direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

No, this can't be done, and I don't see it happening either because the idea of synchronizing everything but deletes is fundamentally against the way we think sync should work.

Unless what you want is to be able to undelete the file at any point in the future... that is something else, and entirely possible.

Comment: I have a doubt and I'd ask you to answer it (IMHO making your answer even clearer): can you currently undelete files in Ubuntu One (as you can in Dropbox, for instance)?

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert just enjoying the Ubuntu One experience.

The only way I can see you doing this is to create a dummy folder as a link and turn off sync with it, then upload the files via the browser to that directory.

I have not tried it but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, and from my experience (someone correct me if I'm wrong) deleting the files on your system also deletes them from the cloud. Maybe one of the Ubuntu One experts knows of a way around this, but so far I don't).