# How to prevent ubuntu one from deleting files

Tags: ubuntu-one

I want ubuntu one to sync existing and new files or directories, but not delete existing files or directories. I use ubuntu one on windows and ubuntu.

The last days I've had multiple times that ubuntu one decided to delete all my files. Fortunately I had just backed up my files and made a local copy of the deleted files. Still, I have no confidence anymore that ubuntu one will safely store my files without suddenly deleting them. So I wondered if there is an option to prevent ubuntu one deleting any files, always keeping a copy of the file in the cloud, even when I delete the file on my computer.

Comment: Related and of interest (but different): http://askubuntu.com/questions/20931/will-deleting-files-on-my-computer-delete-them-them-in-ubuntu-one

Answer (score 1):

if you sync a folder to ubuntu one in your computers then it will be synced in all your computers that have the sync locally option clicked. Example:
- say you create a folder with files in your ubuntu computer.
- Then you sync it with ubuntu one. The content of the folder gets uploaded to the server.
- Now you go to your windows computer and decide to sync that new folder there...then the content of the folder gets downloaded to the windows computer, but STILL REMAINS IN UBUNTU ONE.
- Now if you delete some files in the windows computer from that folder, that will propagate to ubuntu one and to your ubuntu computer, therefore the files will be deleted.

To stop that behavior you have to unclick the sync locally option from your ubuntu one menu in the computer you delete the files.
been using ubuntu one for a while now, keep my backups there and never had such a thing as files deleted by ubuntu one itself.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The bug in my experience is that I do a 'copy to' command of files or a directory from Ubuntu One and it treats the command like a 'move to', and removes the files from Ubuntu One. Nice work Ubuntu One! All the other files on Ubuntu One are stable, so this bug is isolated to a 'copy' as 'move' problem.